# How to avoid looping when selecting query based on two array data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like below.

```
id  supplier_id item_id minimum_order_qty   
1      6           1         500 
2      4           1         300 
3      2           2         200 
4      3           2         100 
5      4           3         250 
6      5           5         100 
7      7           6         1000    
8      8           6         600 
9      9           7         700 
10     1           7         500 
11     7           8         1000    
12     9           9         700 
13     2           10        500 
14     9           10        600
```

Each `item_id` can have more than one supplier(`supplier_id`).

I have two array `item_id` array and `supplier_id` array.

`item_id` array:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 9
        [1] => 10
        [2] => 11
        [3] => 12
        [4] => 13
        [5] => 14
        [6] => 15
        [7] => 16
        [8] => 17
        [9] => 18
        [10] => 19
        [11] => 20
        [12] => 21
        [13] => 22
        [14] => 23
        [15] => 24
    )
```

`supplier_id` array:

```
Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 1
            [5] => 9
            [6] => 6
            [7] => 4
            [8] => 6
            [9] => 9
            [10] => 1
            [11] => 9
            [12] => 9
            [13] => 4
            [14] => 5
            [15] => 9
        )
```

Both array is same length. I want to select `minimum_order_qty` from `supplier_item` based on this two array. Normally, I have to select inside loop like this:

```
$item_count = count($item);
$sup_count = count($supp_id);
for($i=0; $i<$item_count; $i++) {
    $itm_id = $item[$i];
    $s_id = $supp_id[$i];
    $sql = "select * from supplier_item where item_id=$itm_id and supplier_id=$s_id";
    $result[] = $this->query($sql);
}
```

But, the above code will run query many times. I don't want to do this. So, Is there any other way to select data with single query?

Comment: How exactly is this CakePHP related? ps, never insert values into queries directly like that, that's just SQL injection vulnerabilities waiting to be exploitable - use bindings!

Comment: @ndm I just show only sample code. So, I'm not add detail things.

Comment: Well, it's sample code that creates security vulnerabilities, which IMHO should be avoided to be published, as people reading it don't necessarily know that, and are taught bad practice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in one query

```
$item_count = count($item);
$sup_count = count($supp_id);
$predicates = [];
for($i=0; $i<$item_count; $i++) {
    $itm_id = $item[$i];
    $s_id = $supp_id[$i];
    $predicates[] = "(item_id=$itm_id and supplier_id=$s_id)";
}
$sql = "select * from supplier_item where " . implode(' OR ', $predicates);
$result = $this->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

We can take advantage of MySQL's extended `WHERE IN` syntax, and use a query of the form:

```
SELECT *
FROM supplier_item
WHERE (item_id, supplier_id) IN ((9, 9), (10, 2), ...);
```

PHP code:

```
$item_id = array(9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24);
$supplier_id = array(9,2,5,1,1,9,6,4,6,9,1,9,9,4,5,9);

$where = "(";
for ($i=0; $i < count($item_id); $i++) {
    if ($i > 0) $where .= ", ";
    $where .= "(" . $item_id[$i] . ", " . $supplier_id[$i] . ")";
}
$where .= ")";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM supplier_item WHERE (item_id, supplier_id) IN " . $where . ';';
```

**Important note:** Raw string concatenations can leave the door open for SQL injection.  This answer, if used in production, should *only* be used if you have already sterilized the item and supplier ID arrays, and you are *certain* that they only contain integers.